# Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled. ?? ESP32 FreeRTOS Error

Tags: microcontroller, freertos

I was trying to learn FreeRTOS. This is my simple FreeRTOS code that I'm trying to run on my Esp32.

**Code:**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
 #include "freertos/task.h"
 #include "sdkconfig.h"

 TaskHandle_t hello_task_handle = NULL;

 void hello_task(void *p){

     int count = 0;
     while (true){
         printf("%d: Hello Task", count++);
         vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
     }
 }

 void app_main(){

     xTaskCreate(&hello_task, "hello_task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &hello_task_handle);
     vTaskStartScheduler();

     while (true){

     }
 }
```

But I keep getting the following:

**Error Output:**

> ```
> ``ets Jun 8 2016 00:22:57
>
>
> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
>
> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
>
> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
>
> mode:DIO, clock div:2
>
> load:0x3fff0018,len:4
>
> load:0x3fff001c,len:6120
>
> load:0x40078000,len:8816
>
> ho 0 tail 12 room 4
>
> load:0x40080400,len:6412
>
> entry 0x40080748
>
> ␛[0;32mI (30) boot: ESP-IDF 3.30202.190627 2nd stage bootloader␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (31) boot: compile time 11:15:18␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (31) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (36) boot: SPI Speed : 40MHz␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (40) boot: SPI Mode : DIO␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (44) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (48) boot: Partition Table:␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (52) boot: ## Label Usage Type ST Offset Length␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (59) boot: 0 nvs WiFi data 01 02 00009000 00006000␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (67) boot: 1 phy_init RF data 01 01 0000f000 00001000␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (74) boot: 2 factory factory app 00 00 00010000 00100000␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (82) boot: End of partition table␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (86) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x06d9c ( 28060) map␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (104) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x00016dc4 vaddr=0x3ffbdb60 size=0x021e0 ( 8672) load␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (108) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x00018fac vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 ( 1024) load␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (113) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x000193b4 vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x06c5c ( 27740) load␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (132) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00020018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0x13e00 ( 81408) map␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (161) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x00033e20 vaddr=0x4008705c size=0x046d4 ( 18132) load␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (175) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (175) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (175) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (179) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40080f1c␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (170) cpu_start: App cpu up.␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (190) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (197) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 0000F480 (61 KiB): DRAM␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (203) heap_init: At 3FFC1130 len 0001EED0 (123 KiB): DRAM␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (209) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (215) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (222) heap_init: At 4008B730 len 000148D0 (82 KiB): IRAM␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (228) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (246) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.␛[0m
>
> ␛[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.␛[0m
>
> Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
>
> Core 0 register dump:
>
> PC : 0x800d0a02 PS : 0x00050033 A0 : 0x800d0a02 A1 : 0x3ffb1d30
>
> A2 : 0x00000000 A3 : 0x7fffffff A4 : 0x3ffb3990 A5 : 0x454c4449
>
> A6 : 0x3ffb0031 A7 : 0x3ffb2db8 A8 : 0x3ffbec08 A9 : 0x3ffb3e10
>
> A10 : 0x00000000 A11 : 0x00000005 A12 : 0x00000300 A13 : 0x800867f0
>
> A14 : 0x3ffb1db0 A15 : 0x00000000 SAR : 0x00000000 EXCCAUSE: 0x00000014
>
> EXCVADDR: 0x800d0a00 LBEG : 0x00000000 LEND : 0x00000000 LCOUNT : 0x00000000
>
>
>
> Backtrace: 0x400d0a02:0x3ffb1d30 0x400d09ff:0x00000000
>
>
>
> Rebooting...
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The first argument of `xTaskCreate` should be the function, not a function pointer.

I would try this:

```
 xTaskCreate(hello_task, "hello_task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &hello_task_handle);
```

Additionally, if you're using a recent version of ESP-IDF, then `vTaskStartScheduler()` isn't required.

---

EDIT: It might be possible that your lack of `nvs_flash_init()` is causing a problem with the stack. Try calling that function first in your `app_main()`. The recommended way to do so is:

```
esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
    ret = nvs_flash_init();
}
```

Comment: Your claim here is incorrect.  xTaskCreate() does in fact require a function pointer, and in both the asker's code and yours one is being supplied.  The & is optional see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298654/operator-optional-in-function-pointer-assignment

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for that information.

Comment: Please remove the misleading claim.  Have to say your new idea seems like a rather far-fetched guess, why do you think nonvolatile storage is relevant?

Comment: Just as with arrays, the `&` on a function pointer is optional. `hello_task` and `&hello_task` are equivalent.